# Failing to install Python openpyxl module

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have installed the openpyxl Python module in my machine, or at least I thought I've done that. I entered these commands on the command prompt (on Windows):

```
C:\Users\gluti>cd C:\Users\gluti\PycharmProjects\Data Structures\venv\Scripts
C:\Users\gluti\PycharmProjects\Data Structures\venv\Scripts>pip install openpyxl==2.1.4
```

And then, it shows a message, saying that the module openpyxl was successfully installed. However, when I try to import this module on Python IDLE, it shows the following error message:

```
    import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Did I miss something or am I installing the module in the wrong directory?

Comment: Make sure using the same pip version as you are using python. Use pip3 if you are using python-3.x

Comment: Also make sure the venv is activated before you import. The module is installed inside the venv.

Comment: Ok, I have activated the venv and re-installed the module, however in the IDLE it stills displays the same error message

Comment: Open cmd. Run `pip install openpyxl==2.1.4`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have installed python 2 and python 3 so there are two different versions of pip on your machine.

You need to ensure you are installing openpyxl in the same type of python that you are using to run the script.